# external app by package id open in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using appavailability.check plugin to identify the app is avail on device and  if avail then need to open the app but currently get to identify the app is avail but unable to open
please help

Comment: want to open through package id not deep linking

Comment: from which url you are installing plugin?

Comment: appavailability.check  is now working as dowloaded it from the appavailability@4  from v3 native but unable to open a external app from the package Id

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/app-availability/